# Rotate camera in Three.js with mouse

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have quite a few objects in my scene so rotating all of them could be a pain. So what is the most easy way to move camera around origin on mouse click and drag? This way all the lights, objects in the scene are in the same location, so the only thing changing is the camera. Three.js does not provide a way to rotate a camera around a point, or does it?

Thank you

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[Here's a project with a rotating camera](http://mrdoob.com/projects/voxels/). Looking through the source it seems to just move the camera position in a circle.

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    if ( isMouseDown ) {

        theta = - ( ( event.clientX - onMouseDownPosition.x ) * 0.5 )
                + onMouseDownTheta;
        phi = ( ( event.clientY - onMouseDownPosition.y ) * 0.5 )
              + onMouseDownPhi;

        phi = Math.min( 180, Math.max( 0, phi ) );

        camera.position.x = radious * Math.sin( theta * Math.PI / 360 )
                            * Math.cos( phi * Math.PI / 360 );
        camera.position.y = radious * Math.sin( phi * Math.PI / 360 );
        camera.position.z = radious * Math.cos( theta * Math.PI / 360 )
                            * Math.cos( phi * Math.PI / 360 );
        camera.updateMatrix();

    }

    mouse3D = projector.unprojectVector(
        new THREE.Vector3(
            ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1,
            - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1,
            0.5
        ),
        camera
    );
    ray.direction = mouse3D.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize();

    interact();
    render();

}
```

[Here's another demo](http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_terrain_dynamic.html) and in this one I think it just creates a new `THREE.TrackballControls` object with the camera as a parameter, which is probably the better way to go.

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 )
```

Comment: Make sure you add the event listeners. In the source, they look like this: document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

Comment: It fails while doing same as for orthographic trackball controls.Please help me do this with orthographic trackball controls using orthographic camera.

Comment: You mentioned the source code but I can't seem to find it. When I looked at the JS files requested by the app you linked to in the Chrome Dev Tools, I don't see the code you posted above. 

Can you link to the source or explain how you found it please?

I'm mostly curios where/how the isMouseDown and projector variables your code snippet references are defined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 57):

take a look at the following examples

http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit

http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_trackball

there are other examples for different mouse controls, but both of these allow the camera to rotate around a point and zoom in and out with the mouse wheel, the main difference is OrbitControls enforces the camera up direction, and TrackballControls allows the camera to rotate upside-down.

All you have to do is include the controls in your html document

```
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

and include this line in your source

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

Comment: One single line of `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );` can not make it work.You should either add a handler of change event and in the handler call the `renderer.render(scene, camera)`, or add the animation loop and call `controls.update()` in the `animate()`.

Comment: I was able to make this work by just importing the OrbitControls module and instantiating it. No handlers or update calls needed. (It takes a reference to the renderer DOM element to attach the handlers itself and to the renderer to call render itself.)

Answer (score 6):

This might serve as a good starting point for moving/**rotating**/zooming a camera with mouse/trackpad (in typescript):

```
class CameraControl {
    zoomMode: boolean = false
    press: boolean = false
    sensitivity: number = 0.02

    constructor(renderer: Three.Renderer, public camera: Three.PerspectiveCamera, updateCallback:() => void){
        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
            if(!this.press){ return }

            if(event.button == 0){
                camera.position.y -= event.movementY * this.sensitivity
                camera.position.x -= event.movementX * this.sensitivity        
            } else if(event.button == 2){
                camera.quaternion.y -= event.movementX * this.sensitivity/10
                camera.quaternion.x -= event.movementY * this.sensitivity/10
            }

            updateCallback()
        })    

        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', () => { this.press = true })
        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', () => { this.press = false })
        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => { this.press = false })

        document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
            if(event.key == 'Shift'){
                this.zoomMode = true
            }
        })

        document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
            if(event.key == 'Shift'){
                this.zoomMode = false
            }
        })

        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousewheel', event => {
            if(this.zoomMode){ 
                camera.fov += event.wheelDelta * this.sensitivity
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
            } else {
                camera.position.z += event.wheelDelta * this.sensitivity
            }

            updateCallback()
        })
    }
}
```

drop it in like:

```
this.cameraControl = new CameraControl(renderer, camera, () => {
    // you might want to rerender on camera update if you are not rerendering all the time
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => renderer.render(scene, camera))
})
```

Controls:

- move while **[holding mouse left / single finger on trackpad]** to move camera in x/y plane
- move **[mouse wheel / two fingers on trackpad]** to move up/down in z-direction
- **hold shift + [mouse wheel / two fingers on trackpad]** to zoom in/out via increasing/decreasing field-of-view
- move while **holding [mouse right / two fingers on trackpad]** to rotate the camera (quaternion)

Additionally:

If you want to kinda zoom by changing the 'distance' (along yz) instead of changing field-of-view you can bump up/down camera's position y and z while keeping the ratio of position's y and z unchanged like:

```
// in mousewheel event listener in zoom mode
const ratio = camera.position.y / camera.position.z
camera.position.y += (event.wheelDelta * this.sensitivity * ratio)
camera.position.z += (event.wheelDelta * this.sensitivity)
```

Comment: Looks interesting! Do you happen to have a live demo to check out?

Comment: I don't, but It is a good idea, will update the answer with it hopefully these days

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at THREE.PointerLockControls

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js

Answer (score 3):

OrbitControls and TrackballControls seems to be good for this purpose.

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
controls.noZoom = false;
controls.noPan = false;
controls.staticMoving = true;
controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
```

update in render

```
controls.update();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use pointerlock controls from three js
https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/PointerLockControls

Answer (score 2):

Look at simplest [example in doc](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes). Here is a [source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_animation_keyframes.html) for this example.
It's needed to use `THREE.OrbitControls`