# Rotate camera around object with Three.js

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I'm displaying an OBJ element with Three.js using WebGlRenderer, now I'd like to allow users to rotate the camera around the object in any direction, I've found this answer:

[Rotate camera in Three.js with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426822/rotate-camera-in-three-js-with-mouse)

But both examples return me errors, the first says that projector is not defined, and I don't know what it means with "projector". I've just a simple camera, the object and some light. 
The second code says that undefined is not a function.

Does someone know how to get the result I need?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is what you want: http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html

Include the orbit controls (after you have downloaded them):

```
<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Setup the variable:

```
var controls;
```

Attach the controls to the camera and add a listener:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

and in your animate function update the controls:

```
controls.update();
```

[Update] `controls.autoRotate = true;` (tested in v73. Recent versions of OrbitControls.js has added this control.)

Comment: Thank you but now is the item that rotates around the camera... how can I invert the behavior? thanks

Comment: @FezVrasta You can choose what to orbit so instead of camera you can put an object in there if you like for example "sphere" so it would be: new THREE.OrbitControls( sphere );

Comment: Thanks but I can't make it works, I use this code to load the OBJ: http://jsfiddle.net/7aqmB/ but if I use _object_ in **OrbitControls** it says that object is undefined...

Comment: @FezVrasta three.js is an option in Fiddle, could you add your whole code?

Comment: Sorry was just a problem with the position of the camera, in fact is the camera that rotates around the object just as I've asked, perfect.

Comment: Not a problem. Would love to see what you're working on at some point?

Comment: I don't know how to include the .obj and the texture in JSfiddle, I'm working for a company and I can't use my server to host a demo.

Comment: It's not necessary to write `controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );` in the code. The library is doing it itself. And `controls.update()` must be inside the `function render(){...}`, NOT in the `function animate(){...}`

Comment: ... even is not necessary to use `controls.update()` in `render()`. It will work.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to mess with `OrbitControls`, simply add the camera to a boom `Group`

```
  const boom = new THREE.Group();
  boom.add(camera);
  scene.add(boom);
  camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 ); // this sets the boom's length 
  camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 ); // camera looks at the boom's zero
```

then you can rotate this boom instead of the camera itself.

```
  boom.rotation.x += 0.01;
```

You may want to add some extra objects, like lights etc. to this boom, btw

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick hack, in case you don't want to use the OrbitControls for some reason.

```
            camera.position.copy( target );
            camera.position.x+=Math.sin(camera.rotationy)*3;
            camera.position.z+=Math.cos(camera.rotationy)*3;
            camera.position.y+=cameraHeight; // optional
            tempVector.copy(target).y+=cameraHeight; // the += is optional
            camera.lookAt( tempVector );
```

camera.rotationy is a copy of the mouse rotation value since we are changing it with the call to lookAt.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ES6, following could be used for OrbitControls

```
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

// this would create the orbit controls
// it would allow camera control using mouse
const orbitControls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

If you need autorotate,

```
function init() {
  ...

  // following would enable autorotate
  const orbitControls.autoRotate = true;

  ..
}

function animate() {
  // need to update the orbitcontrols for autorotate camera to take effect
  orbitControls.update();

  ...
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
```

For ref: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if you substitute 'camera' with the object of your choice, the object will rotate. But if there are other objects surrounding it (for example a grid on the floor), they will still stand still. That might be what you want, or it might look weird. (Imagine a chair rotating floating above the floor...?)

I choose to override the center object from OrbitControls.JS from my code after initializing the Orbit Controls

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
…
controls.center =  new THREE.Vector3(
    chair.position.x,
    chair.position.y,
    chair.position.z
);
```

(disclaimer: I have the impression there are different versions of OrbitControls.js around, but I assume they all use this center-object)

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to trigger render method on change of `OrbitControl`:

```
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableDamping = true;   //damping 
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;   //damping inertia
    controls.enableZoom = true;      //Zooming
    controls.autoRotate = true;       // enable rotation
    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2; // Limit angle of visibility

   controls.addEventListener("change", () => {
      if (this.renderer) this.renderer.render(this.scene, camera);
    });
```

and in animate update controls:

```
  start = () => {
    if (!this.frameId) {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    }
  };
  stop = () => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
  };

  renderScene = () => {
    if (this.renderer) this.renderer.render(this.scene, camera);
  };


animate = () => {
    // update controls
    controls.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra info for who looking auto rotate direction change on a limit:

```
if (
   controls.getAzimuthalAngle() >= Math.PI / 2 ||
   controls.getAzimuthalAngle() <= -Math.PI / 2
 ) {
   controls.autoRotateSpeed *= -1;
 }

 controls.update();
```