# THREE.PointerLockControls() returning "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to implement a moving camera in THREE like so:

```
function initThree(){
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,1000);
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00});
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.z=5;
    controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera); //fails at this line

}
```

At the line marked, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

However, there is an example of it on [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js) page? I'm currently using a local copy of [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/build/three.min.js) THREE build.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you sure it's included in that build? I did a search and it didn't turn up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because the [controls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js/controls) are not part of the [main source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src). If you want to use the controls, you probably need to include them separately. See this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466578/rotate-camera-around-object-with-three-js).