# Three.js add a rotating camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/2151/

After a reading a few articles i am at a loss.

[Rotate camera around object with Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466578/rotate-camera-around-object-with-three-js)

Below is simple code for a cube rotating with a floor. This should hopefully be a simple example to follow.

I am trying to add a camera so on click and drag it rotates around the scene. Similar to this http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_trackball

> For anyone with the same quesiton lets get you to my point below:

Download three.js here:

http://threejs.org/

You need to have something call orbit controls in your js folder. You will find a link to orbitcontrols to download here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3587259/Code/Threejs/OrbitControls.js

Copy this and put it in your site folder.

You then need to link to orbit control and three.js it in your html. Like the below:

```
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
```

Then see below for a simple wireframe cube with a floor.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper( 5 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//This breaks it?
//controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(2,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);


var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {wireframe: true} );
var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
floor.position.y = -50.0;
floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;

scene.add(floor);

camera.position.z = 3;

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    cube.rotation.z += 0.005;
    cube.rotation.x += 0.005;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

Comment: You could create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to help us a little. Try leaving out the `renderer.domElement` argument maybe? What exactly does happen when you run the code, any errors?

Comment: Get the `OrbitControls`, and the three.js library from the three.js site. Make sure they are all from the same release.

Comment: js fiddle added, the floor doesn't seem to be rendering.