# Threejs rotate around object with mouse? (no mouseDown)

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I am looking for a way to rotate around an object in Threejs but without holding the mouse button. I've got an example website here: http://www.dilladimension.com/ which uses Threejs. Been looking through forums and on the Threejs documentation but I can't figure out how to rotate around an object without holding down the mouse.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get that kind of mouse interaction as shown [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ctm), you can :

```
//Listen to mouse mouve events
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );
}


//Update your camera position
function render() {
    camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
    camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks good, very close but not yet there. The movement is spot on I just want to know if there is a way to go full 360 around an object? I am a bit of a noob with Javascript so bare with me!

Comment: @Bayron2304, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426822/rotate-camera-in-three-js-with-mouse) might help then (you need to adapt the code and remove the part checking if a mouse button is clicked)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!